# How to do group_by_rolling grouped by day by hour in polars in Python?

Tags: python, python-polars

Let's say you have a dataset with the following column, Node, Time, date, Hour, Amount.  Time is spaced hourly. date is simply the current date corresponding to Time.  You should have only one instance of a Node per hour.

Every day, for every Hour I want the average of Amount for the past 31 days in this hour.  Here is the first thing I tried:

```
df.group_by_rolling('Time', period='31d', by=['date', 'Hour']).agg(pl.col('Amount').mean())
```

I expected to get back one row per Hour per day, but I got the same amount of rows as the original df:

[image]

What is it calculating exactly here and how can I do what I want it to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't post screen captures, try (`print(df.to_init_repr())`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from @keraion is the closest, but unfortunately it is super slow when you have a lot of rows and also fill up 128GB of ram in 5s.  2000 nodes per hour, which gives around 17_520_000 rows per year...

Here is the solution I came up with which is fast.  I calculate the mean in two steps.  First group_by date and hour and calculate the sum of Amount and the count.  This is only for a single day though.  Then I can do a group_by_rolling of the last 31 days and calculate the mean by using the accumulated sum and count I had calculated by day:

```
dfinal = (
    dfrank.lazy()
    .group_by(['date', 'Hour'])
    .agg(
        AmountSum = pl.col('Amount').sum(),
        AmountCount = pl.count()
    )
    .sort(['date', 'Hour'])
    .group_by_rolling('date', period=f'31d', by=['Hour'])
    .agg(
        (pl.col('AmountSum ').sum() / pl.col('AmountCount').sum()).alias('AmountMean ')
    )
    .with_columns(
        Time = (pl.col('date').cast(pl.Datetime('ns')) + pl.duration(hours=pl.col('Hour')))
    )
    .collect()
)
```

This gives us the mean by date by Hour for the last 31 days.  This is super fast even for millions of rows.  Sub 1s.  I also wanted to calculate quantiles though and my trick of accumulating sums and counts per day could not work here, so instead I accumulate list of numbers and flatten it in the group_by_rolling:

```
dfinal = (df.lazy()
    .group_by(['date', 'Hour'])
    .agg(
        pl.col('Amount')
    )
    .sort(['date', 'Hour'])
    .group_by_rolling('date', period=f'31d', by=['Hour'])
    .agg(
        AmountMedian = pl.col('Amount').flatten().quantile(0.5)
    )
    .with_columns(
        Time = (pl.col('date').cast(pl.Datetime('ns')) + pl.duration(hours=pl.col('Hour')))
    )
    .collect()
)
```

This last solution is not as fast (takes ~11s), but allows me to calculate any function in the group_by_rolling.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your requirements correctly, there are a few changes that must be made to get the per day per hour 31-day lookback.

First, the `by=['date', 'Hour']` is limiting your period lookback to a single day, this needs to be changed to `by=["Hour"]`.

Second, after `date` has been removed `group_by_rolling` is going to return a record **per node**, per hour, per day with a 31-day lookback. You will need to `filter` after the `agg` to the return the `mean` of all nodes. This can be done using `is_last` on `Time`.

Example data setup:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import polars as pl

df = (
    pl.DataFrame(
        {
            "Time": pl.date_range(
                datetime(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
                datetime(2022, 3, 31, 23, 0, 0),
                "1h",
                eager=True,
            ),
            "Amount": range(1, 2161),
        }
    )
    # act like we have a constant three nodes, but this solution acts the same with variable amounts
    .with_columns(pl.col("Time").repeat_by(3)) 
    .explode("Time")
    .with_columns(pl.col("Time").dt.hour().alias("Hour"))
)
```

Example data:

```
shape: (6_480, 3)
┌─────────────────────┬────────┬──────┐
│ Time                ┆ Amount ┆ Hour │
│ ---                 ┆ ---    ┆ ---  │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64    ┆ u32  │
╞═════════════════════╪════════╪══════╡
│ 2022-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 1      ┆ 0    │
│ 2022-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 1      ┆ 0    │
│ 2022-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 1      ┆ 0    │
│ 2022-01-01 01:00:00 ┆ 2      ┆ 1    │
│ …                   ┆ …      ┆ …    │
│ 2022-03-31 22:00:00 ┆ 2159   ┆ 22   │
│ 2022-03-31 23:00:00 ┆ 2160   ┆ 23   │
│ 2022-03-31 23:00:00 ┆ 2160   ┆ 23   │
│ 2022-03-31 23:00:00 ┆ 2160   ┆ 23   │
└─────────────────────┴────────┴──────┘
```

To help show what this is doing, I'll include some additional columns. This is the aggregation pre-filter:

```py
print(
    df.sort("Time")
    .group_by_rolling("Time", period="31d", by=["Hour"])
    .agg(
        pl.col("Amount").mean(),
        pl.col("Amount").alias("amt_list"),
        pl.col("Amount").sum().alias("amt_sum"),
        pl.col("Amount").len().alias("amt_len"),
    )
)
```

Results:

```
shape: (6_480, 6)
┌──────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────┬──────────────────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ Hour ┆ Time                ┆ Amount      ┆ amt_list             ┆ amt_sum ┆ amt_len │
│ ---  ┆ ---                 ┆ ---         ┆ ---                  ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ u32  ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ f64         ┆ list[i64]            ┆ i64     ┆ u32     │
╞══════╪═════════════════════╪═════════════╪══════════════════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ 0    ┆ 2022-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 1.0         ┆ [1]                  ┆ 1       ┆ 1       │
│ 0    ┆ 2022-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 1.0         ┆ [1, 1]               ┆ 2       ┆ 2       │
│ 0    ┆ 2022-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 1.0         ┆ [1, 1, 1]            ┆ 3       ┆ 3       │
│ 0    ┆ 2022-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 7.0         ┆ [1, 1, … 25]         ┆ 28      ┆ 4       │
│ 0    ┆ 2022-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 10.6        ┆ [1, 1, … 25]         ┆ 53      ┆ 5       │
│ 0    ┆ 2022-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 13.0        ┆ [1, 1, … 25]         ┆ 78      ┆ 6       │
│ 0    ┆ 2022-01-03 00:00:00 ┆ 18.142857   ┆ [1, 1, … 49]         ┆ 127     ┆ 7       │
│ 0    ┆ 2022-01-03 00:00:00 ┆ 22.0        ┆ [1, 1, … 49]         ┆ 176     ┆ 8       │
│ 0    ┆ 2022-01-03 00:00:00 ┆ 25.0        ┆ [1, 1, … 49]         ┆ 225     ┆ 9       │
│ 0    ┆ 2022-01-04 00:00:00 ┆ 29.8        ┆ [1, 1, … 73]         ┆ 298     ┆ 10      │
│ …    ┆ …                   ┆ …           ┆ …                    ┆ …       ┆ …       │
│ 23   ┆ 2022-03-28 23:00:00 ┆ 1728.0      ┆ [1368, 1368, … 2088] ┆ 160704  ┆ 93      │
│ 23   ┆ 2022-03-29 23:00:00 ┆ 1744.087912 ┆ [1392, 1392, … 2112] ┆ 158712  ┆ 91      │
│ 23   ┆ 2022-03-29 23:00:00 ┆ 1748.086957 ┆ [1392, 1392, … 2112] ┆ 160824  ┆ 92      │
│ 23   ┆ 2022-03-29 23:00:00 ┆ 1752.0      ┆ [1392, 1392, … 2112] ┆ 162936  ┆ 93      │
│ 23   ┆ 2022-03-30 23:00:00 ┆ 1768.087912 ┆ [1416, 1416, … 2136] ┆ 160896  ┆ 91      │
│ 23   ┆ 2022-03-30 23:00:00 ┆ 1772.086957 ┆ [1416, 1416, … 2136] ┆ 163032  ┆ 92      │
│ 23   ┆ 2022-03-30 23:00:00 ┆ 1776.0      ┆ [1416, 1416, … 2136] ┆ 165168  ┆ 93      │
│ 23   ┆ 2022-03-31 23:00:00 ┆ 1792.087912 ┆ [1440, 1440, … 2160] ┆ 163080  ┆ 91      │
│ 23   ┆ 2022-03-31 23:00:00 ┆ 1796.086957 ┆ [1440, 1440, … 2160] ┆ 165240  ┆ 92      │
│ 23   ┆ 2022-03-31 23:00:00 ┆ 1800.0      ┆ [1440, 1440, … 2160] ┆ 167400  ┆ 93      │
└──────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────┴──────────────────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

From the January records, you see the rolling window begin to be built out, but each hour has 3 records (3 nodes). This is fine. As you see in the March records each hour is ending with 93 records (3 nodes * 31 days). From this point, the interest is only in the final record per hour, after all the `Amount` values have been evaluated. Because we needed to sort on `Time` for the `group_by_rolling`, we can use `is_last` on `Time` to only return the final record for each hour.

```py
print(
    df.sort("Time")
    .group_by_rolling("Time", period="31d", by=["Hour"])
    .agg(
        pl.col("Amount").mean(),
        pl.col("Amount").alias("amt_list"),
        pl.col("Amount").sum().alias("amt_sum"),
        pl.col("Amount").len().alias("amt_len"),
    )
    .filter(pl.col("Time").is_last())
)
```

Results:

```
shape: (2_160, 6)
┌──────┬─────────────────────┬────────┬──────────────────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ Hour ┆ Time                ┆ Amount ┆ amt_list             ┆ amt_sum ┆ amt_len │
│ ---  ┆ ---                 ┆ ---    ┆ ---                  ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ u32  ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ f64    ┆ list[i64]            ┆ i64     ┆ u32     │
╞══════╪═════════════════════╪════════╪══════════════════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ 0    ┆ 2022-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 1.0    ┆ [1, 1, 1]            ┆ 3       ┆ 3       │
│ 0    ┆ 2022-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 13.0   ┆ [1, 1, … 25]         ┆ 78      ┆ 6       │
│ 0    ┆ 2022-01-03 00:00:00 ┆ 25.0   ┆ [1, 1, … 49]         ┆ 225     ┆ 9       │
│ 0    ┆ 2022-01-04 00:00:00 ┆ 37.0   ┆ [1, 1, … 73]         ┆ 444     ┆ 12      │
│ …    ┆ …                   ┆ …      ┆ …                    ┆ …       ┆ …       │
│ 23   ┆ 2022-03-28 23:00:00 ┆ 1728.0 ┆ [1368, 1368, … 2088] ┆ 160704  ┆ 93      │
│ 23   ┆ 2022-03-29 23:00:00 ┆ 1752.0 ┆ [1392, 1392, … 2112] ┆ 162936  ┆ 93      │
│ 23   ┆ 2022-03-30 23:00:00 ┆ 1776.0 ┆ [1416, 1416, … 2136] ┆ 165168  ┆ 93      │
│ 23   ┆ 2022-03-31 23:00:00 ┆ 1800.0 ┆ [1440, 1440, … 2160] ┆ 167400  ┆ 93      │
└──────┴─────────────────────┴────────┴──────────────────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

Here we have our result, each hour's value independent of any other hour of the day's value and looking back 31 days. The `amt_list`, `amt_sum`, and `amt_len` columns can be removed from the `agg` step. If the original `date` value was needed, `.with_columns(pl.col("Time").dt.date().alias("date"))` can add it back to the resulting `DataFrame`.

#### Updated Answer for less RAM usage

To combat the memory requirements of a `group_by_rolling`, the nodes can be pre-aggregated by doing a `group_by` on `Time` and `Hour`, and getting the `sum` and `count` values as `amt_sum` and `amt_count`, then do the `group_by_rolling` the same way, but calculating the mean manually over the `sum` of `amt_sum` divided by the `sum` of `amt_count`. This also removes the need for the `filter` of `is_last`.

```py
print(
    df.group_by("Time", "Hour")
    .agg(
        pl.col("Amount").sum().alias("amt_sum"),
        pl.col("Amount").count().alias("amt_count"),
    )
    .sort("Time")
    .group_by_rolling("Time", period="31d", by=["Hour"])
    .agg(
        (pl.col("amt_sum").sum() / pl.col("amt_count").sum()).alias("Amount"),
    )
    .with_columns(pl.col("Time").dt.date().alias("date"))
)
```

I was able to get this to run for a full year with over 10,000 nodes (~93 million records) on a system with 16GB of RAM.

Comment: Interesting!  The problem with my dataset is that this is extremely slow.  My df has millions of rows.  I have 128gb of ram and it fills up the ram in 5s.

Comment: @EtienneT - I've added an update that might help with the memory issue. It pre-aggregates the nodes and manually runs the mean in the `group_by_rolling`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want `group_by_rolling` if you just want the last 31 days' worth of data. Just a regular `group_by` with a `tail` in the `agg`:

```py
df = pl.from_dict({
    'date' : pl.date_range(date(2022, 1, 1), date(2022, 12, 31), '1h', eager=True),
    'amount' : range(8737, 1, -1)
})

df.group_by(pl.col('date').dt.hour(), maintain_order=True).agg(pl.col('amount').tail(31).mean())
```

(`maintain_order=True` is set just for consistent output below - this is slower. You may want that order, nonetheless.)

```
shape: (24, 2)
┌──────┬────────┐
│ date ┆ amount │
│ ---  ┆ ---    │
│ u32  ┆ f64    │
╞══════╪════════╡
│ 0    ┆ 361.0  │
│ 1    ┆ 384.0  │
│ 2    ┆ 383.0  │
│ 3    ┆ 382.0  │
│ 4    ┆ 381.0  │
│ 5    ┆ 380.0  │
│ 6    ┆ 379.0  │
│ 7    ┆ 378.0  │
│ 8    ┆ 377.0  │
│ 9    ┆ 376.0  │
│ 10   ┆ 375.0  │
│ 11   ┆ 374.0  │
│ 12   ┆ 373.0  │
│ 13   ┆ 372.0  │
│ 14   ┆ 371.0  │
│ 15   ┆ 370.0  │
│ 16   ┆ 369.0  │
│ 17   ┆ 368.0  │
│ 18   ┆ 367.0  │
│ 19   ┆ 366.0  │
│ 20   ┆ 365.0  │
│ 21   ┆ 364.0  │
│ 22   ┆ 363.0  │
│ 23   ┆ 362.0  │
└──────┴────────┘
```

Comment: I dont think this works because I also have the Node column can have 2000 different nodes for an hour.  Each node has one row per hour, but I there's multiple nodes.  If I take the tail(31) within the Hour group, I won't really get the last 31 days, I might just get the last 31 nodes in the last hour.

Comment: Can you post a minimal reproducible example then, because that wasn't clear.